# Can you retrieve the TTL in Redis c#?

Tags: c#, stackexchange.redis

Is there any way to get the TTL (Time to Live) of a StackExchange.Redis key in c#?

Comment: TTL is Time to Live or Time to License?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I have little experience with redis but I believe you are referring to: (http://redis.io/commands/ttl).

If so, try running the .KeyTimeToLive("RedisKeyHere") on your database connection object.

See example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        ConnectionMultiplexer redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost");

        var db = redis.GetDatabase(0);
        var timeToLive = db.KeyTimeToLive("RedisKeyNameHere");

    }
}
```

I hope this information helps!

Comment: Yup, that should do it

Comment: Thanks, I thought I searched that entire list for IDatabase.  You're a life saver.

Comment: Is it possible to get the ttls for multiple keys in one call ?