# In Redis, can we check age of cache?

Tags: c#, redis

We are storing a serialized object in to Redis cache. We want to check the age of cache before retrieving new data and update the cache. If it is less than 10 mins, as data might not have changed in that duration, so we pull from cache and send to API output. if not, we will still return cached data to output, request new pull of data, update cache if new data is available and intimate the web listener to get latest update.

Is there a way with existing cache API, that we can check the age of Redis cache key? If no, any workarounds?

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28797253/can-you-retrieve-the-ttl-in-redis-c/28797857 that will help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking at it from the wrong perspective.

What would happen if you were to use Redis' [`EXPIRE`](https://redis.io/commands/expire) with a TTL of 10min for each of your cache's keys? Redis will keep the data for 10min and then expire it, simplifying the application's logic. You would no longer need to actively check the "age" of the key - if it isn't in Redis then you need to fetch (for reference look up the so-called "Cache Aside" pattern).

Comment: Both methods are not equivalent. In some use cases it is more important to get any data right now than getting fresh data (especially when refreshing data is a very long process).